# How to dismiss parent view from View Controller in Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, dismiss

My app have a main screen (`mainView`). On `mainView`, I have a button. When user taps it, I use

```
[self presentViewController:libraryView animated:YES completion:nil]
```

to present another view (`libraryView`). Then, on `libraryView`, I use

```
[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view]
```

to add a `UITabBarController` which has 2 View Controllers: `featuredBooks` and `recentBooks`

Everything works fine. But when I add a button to `featureBooks` to dissmiss the `libraryView` and return to `mainView`, the following methods don't work

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion:nil]
[self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion:nil]
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion:nil]
```

I know the reason: `self` refers to `featureBooks`'s view, not `libraryView`.

So, how do I refer to `libraryView`, dismiss it and return to `mainView` from a view controller (`featureBooks` or `recentBooks`) inside Tab Bar Controller?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Make mainView delegate object of libraryView... Then when you call the delegate method from libraryView, mainView will call in its code the method dismissViewcController.

So:

1)create into libraryView controller .h code:

```
@protocol LibraryViewDelegate

      - (void) LibraryViewDelegate_DismissButtonClicked;

@end
```

2)then create a property into mainView .h file:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSObject<LibraryViewDelegate> *delegate;
```

and the following into the .m one

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

and assign mainView to this property after libraryView object creation and before you will present it

3)write the following code into the mainview .m file:

```
-(void)LibraryViewDelegate_DismissButtonClicked{
      //put here the code for dismissing mainView created modalViewController (libraryView)
}
```

4)then write the code that call:

```
[self.delegate LibraryViewDelegate_DismissButtonClicked];
```

into libraryView when you press the dismiss button

Comment: Thank you for your answer and example code. After asking for example code, I've searched and deleted my comment :P Anyway, thank you.

But, I think you may misunderstand me. I want to dismiss `libraryView` from `featuredBooks` (a View Controller of a Tab Bar Controller. And that Tab Bar Controller is a subview of `libraryView`). I've tried your code but it didn't work the way I want.

Thanks again for your code.

Comment: Finally, I made it. I don't use Interface Builder anymore, and create the Tab Bar Controller, View Controller programmatically. Now delegate works fine.